# How do I remove wallpaper when it is close to a cupboard?

Tags: walls, kitchens, wallpaper, removal

I have wallpaper close to a cupboard as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

I'm looking for a way to remove it, without removing the cupboard.

Is there a technique that can do that?

Thanks.

Update:

---

This is the result. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can see something in that picture but I am sure most others will agree that about all that is clear is a couple of green rectangles. Can you try for something closer and a lot more in focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an Exacto knife or razor knife to neatly score along the edge of the cupboards.

Then soak the wallpaper with hot water from a sponge and then use a teakettle or other source of steam to loosen the paper until you can scrape it off with a putty knife.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @ArchonOSX, thanks, I was able to remove the wallpaper in a clean manner.